# C - Segmentation fault on for loop using pointers & function

Tags: c

I've got some trouble about a C function.

This is the function:

```
int* CalcMeanPower(int Media[], int** MeanPowerArray, int righe, int colonne)
{
  int i=0, k=0;
  int ArrayPower[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};

  for (i=0; i<righe; i++)
  {
    for (k=0; k<colonne; k++)
    {
      ArrayPower[k] = ArrayPower[k] + MeanPowerArray[i][k]  ;
    }
  }

  for (k=0; k<colonne; k++)
  {
    Media[k] = (ArrayPower[k]/righe);
  }

  return Media;
}
```

This is how I call the function from the main:

VettoreMedia = CalcMeanPower(VettoreMedia, RefMeanPower, num_mean, N);

,where the variables are defined as follows:

```
int* RefMeanPower[N];
int* VettoreMedia;
int N=4, num_mean=5;
```

When I try to run the program it returns me a segmentation fault while trying to do:

```
 for (k=0; k<colonne; k++)
  {
    Media[k] = (ArrayPower[k]/righe);
  }
```

Could you please explain me what I'm doing wrong? I've searched through the net but I can't find the answer. This function is only a little piece of my C program, but I'm sure it faults in this cycle!

Please Help..

Comment: Is `ArrayPower` large enough?  What is the value of `colonne`?  Most likely you are going over the end of the array.

Comment: Closing as too localized.

Comment: You do not show how you allocate storage for int* RefMeanPower[N];
int* VettoreMedia;

Answer (score 1):

u have not initialized VetorreMedia befor passing to the function. since this is not initialized,Media also is pointing to unknown location so segmentation fault. VetorreMedia should have some default value.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this in a debugger you will see where your segfault is occurring and be able to solve it from there.

Google `gdb cheatsheet` to get started.

Comment: Thank you guys! Now it works! This is only a little part about my program. I'm doing an algorith for RFID localization and maybe I'll post some other question during these days..

How can I initialize this kind of vector pointer?


'char** RefIdTagArray;
 char** IdXTagArray;'

@x539

Really thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reserve memory for your variables/arrays.

`RefMeanPower` is just a array of plain uninitialized pointers. And `VettoreMedia` is just a plain uninitialized pointer.

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  RefMeanPower[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * num_mean);

// don't forget to free after usage
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  free(RefMeanPower[i]);
```

Where you get `RefMeanPower[N][num_mean]` so swap `k` and `i` as indices or `N` and `num_mean` on creation.

and for `VettoreMedia` you can do

```
VettoreMedia = malloc(sizeof(int) * N);

// don't forget to free after usage
free(VettoreMedia);
```

or

```
int VettoreMedia[N];
// frees automatically when leaving scope
```

Comment: Thank you x539! Now it works! This is only a little part about my program. I'm doing an algorith for RFID localization and maybe I'll post some other question during these days..

How can I initialize this kind of vector pointer?


'char** RefIdTagArray;
 char** IdXTagArray;'

@x539

Really thanks in advance!

Comment: Found it googling.. Thank you guys!